# Get a custom table to an array

Tags: plugin-development, database, query

How can I take my table I created like this:

```
global $wpdb; //Get all the wordpress database stuff
$table_prefix = $wpdb->base_prefix; //Get the global prefix for all sites (on a multisite installation)
$table_name = $table_prefix.'wpaa';//Add   wpaa   behind the prefix 

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `".$table_name."` (....) "; //Create table and its rows. (Rows are ...'d out)

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' ); //Require something you have to include
dbDelta( $sql ); //Make the actual query
```

and get all the data out from it in form of an array.

---

I know how I would do in regular PHP (without wordpress):

```
$sql = 'SELECT id,foo,bar FROM wp_wpaa';
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error at looking up in database');
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: You are familiar with `$wpdb`. [Check the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). Everything you need for this is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$wpdb->get_results();` has a second parameter for the return format:

```
/**
 * Retrieve an entire SQL result set from the database (i.e., many rows)
 *
 * Executes a SQL query and returns the entire SQL result.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 *
 * @param string $query SQL query.
 * @param string $output Optional. 
 * Any of ARRAY_A | ARRAY_N | OBJECT | OBJECT_K constants. 
 * With one of the first three, return an array of rows indexed from 0 by SQL 
 * result row number.
 *  Each row is an associative array (column => value, ...), a numerically 
 *      indexed array (0 => value, ...), or an object. ( ->column = value ), 
 *      respectively.
 *  With OBJECT_K, return an associative array of row objects keyed by the 
 *      value of each row's first column's value. Duplicate keys are discarded.
 * @return mixed Database query results
 */
function get_results( $query = null, $output = OBJECT ) {
```

So this will return an array:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );
```

Comment: Tank you! I just didn't know how to get the output as an array

Answer (score 0):

you can take every rows from a table **YOUR_TABALE_NAME**

`"SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}YOUR_TABALE_NAME"`

then with the `get_results()` return it into an array `$array`

finally you have somthing like this one :

```php
    global $wpdb;
    $array = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}YOUR_TABALE_NAME");
    print_r($array); // print the array
```

Comment: The original question wanted each row to be an array though, and the extra parameter in the other answer does that I think. How is this different to / better than the other answer?